# Spring REStful web service @initbinder not allowing other validation

Tags: java, spring, web-services, restful-architecture, spring-restcontroller

I have the following Rest controller:

```
 @RestController
 public class DocumentSearchController_global 
{
@InitBinder//("TestCustomAnotation")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
   binder.setValidator(new ChekAtleastOneValueValidator());

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/validator", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
protected DocumentSearchResponse validatortest(@Valid @RequestBody TestCustomAnotation objDMSRequest,  Errors e, BindingResult br) throws AppException
{
    if(br.hasErrors())
        System.out.println("ERRor");
  if (e.hasErrors())
  {
      System.out.println("Got Error:      "+ e.getFieldError());
  }
    DocumentSearchResponse objDocSearchResponse =  null;


    return objDocSearchResponse;
    }




@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public String handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException  error) {
    System.out.println("ERROR-->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" +error.getMessage());
    return "Bad request: " + error.getMessage();
}
}
```

And this is the bean where the request will be cast:

```
        public class TestCustomAnotation
        {
        @ValidDocumentModifiedDate({"7Days", "30Days","60Days"})
        String docModifiedDate;
        @NotNull
        String objectId;
        @NotNull
        String jobId;

        Setter and GEtter
        }
```

1. In the controller if I specify `binder.setValidator(new
   ChekAtleastOneValueValidator());` the contol will only go to
   `ChekAtleastOneValueValidator` it will not check for `@notnull`
   @ValidDocumentModifiedDate`
2. If I don't have `binder.setValidator(new
   ChekAtleastOneValueValidator());`  then the control will check for
   `@notnull@ValidDocumentModifiedDate` validation but not
   `ChekAtleastOneValueValidator`.

My question is: is there a way in Spring to use ***Spring validation, custom annotation and @notnull annotation*** and get all the error of all the validation or spring allows to use only Spring validators?

Comment: You need a [`CompositeValidator`](https://github.com/mdeinum/spring-utils/blob/master/validation/src/main/java/biz/deinum/multitenant/validation/CompositeValidator.java) which wraps around multiple other validators. Inject the 2 validators you want executed and inject the composite instance the `WebDataBinder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the question itself was wrong. I got the answer I use a Spring Validator class to validate all the request comming in and then use @validated in stead of @valid. I don't use annotation at the request anymore and let the class be a POJO. thats it problem solved